# Mono view supported .net frameworks

Tags: mono

Is there any way of viewing which .Net frameworks are currently installed/supported by my installation of mono? Currently using a Ubuntu Server 18.04 system.

Using the command `# mono -V` tells me the Mono JIT compiler version is 5.18.0.240, which doesn't really help me much.

My end goal is to try and use mod_mono for Apache to run an ASP.Net web app using .Net framework 4.5.2